# Why I am Stuck in infinite loop

Tags: python, infinite-loop

Can someone tell me why I am stuck in an infinite loop? I can't find what is wrong. I have tried to print out items to at least find out where the problem is coming from and I think it's occurring after where practiceBalance > 0. Other than that, I haven't been able to figure it out! Thanks!

```
count = 0
while count<12:

    count +=1

    if practiceBalance < 0:
        count = 0
    elif practiceBalance > 0:
        count = 0
    elif practiceBalance == 0:
        break
```

Comment: you are making your `count` equal to 0 in `if` and `elif` condition..so it goes in infinite lop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you print `practiceBalance` you'll notice this:

```
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
practiceBalance: 298222.561111
...
```

Hence, it is always greater than `0`. Hence in this clause:

```
elif practiceBalance > 0:
    low = monthlyPayment   
    practiceBalance = balance
    count = 0
```

You always reset `count` to `0`

Comment: But won't the 'elif' statement run only one time? I thought that's how it worked. I thought only 'while' statements continued looping?

Comment: @MeMyself: All the if/elif/else statements are checked each time you run through the loop, because they are inside the loop.

Comment: I've tried rewriting it as a function...it's still a work in progress, but I am still not getting a correct answer. Although, the infinite loop stopped.

Comment: @MeMyself since this answer helped you work out the infinite looping problem, I suggest you accept it (the green tick next to the answer), have a good go at working out the rest yourself, and come back to the site with another question (possibly referencing this one if applicable) later if you still have issues - just make sure you produce code and your attempts that you've tried... good luck